# jQuery return selected options attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

if I have the html

```
<select id="autoplay">
    <option data-autoplay="">no</option>
    <option data-autoplay="1">yes</option>
</select>
```

how using jQuery can I return the `data-autoplay` value in respect to which option is selected and set it as a variable `var autoplay = *selected value*`

so if I select `no` it returns nothing and if I select `yes` it returns 1 so `var autoplay = "1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code,

```
$("#autoplay option:selected").attr("data-autoplay");
```

or

```
$("#autoplay option:selected").data("autoplay");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `attr()` method to get the value of an attribute:

```
var autopplay =  $('#autoplay option:selected').attr('data-autoplay');

if (!autoplay || autoplay == '') {
    // an empty string was returned
}
else if (autoplay == 1) {
    /* remember not to trust your users, so validate in/on the server
       if you're storing the variable/result...
    // 1 was returned
}
```

It's possible to also use `data('autoplay')`, which will look at `data-` prefixed attributes with a string matching the selector (autoplay) following the `data-`, so in this case it would look for: `data-autoplay` (somewhat obviously, I suppose).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).